# opensuse tumbleweed cannot install latest version of opencv

Tags: opensuse, zypper, opencv

Available opencv version for tumbleweed on the website https://software.opensuse.org/package/opencv is listed 3.2, but when I try installing it on my laptop version 3.1 is installed. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at my package list and found that the latest version of ***opencv*** is in the Education repository:

```
zypper info opencv
```

> Version        : 3.2.0-95.4
>   Arch           : x86_64
>   Vendor         : openSUSE-Education
>   Installed Size : 10.1 MiB
>   Installed      : No
>   Status         : not installed
>   Source package : opencv-3.2.0-95.4.src
>   Summary        : Collection of algorithms for computer vision

So, you should add Education repository for installing the latest version of ***opencv***:

```
zypper ar -f -n education http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Education/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/ education
```

Comment: Thanks! They have a really bad website then, I will probably switch to ArchLinux

Comment: @hovo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/ You can find a lots of repositories here. You are right, there are lots of strange things in the website and wiki of openSUSE. But I don't believe openSUSE is bad distro.